# How do I connect to a Windows 10 fileserver?

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-server

I`m planning to install Ubuntu on my HTPC (Intel NUC DN2820) again, and I also got a fileserver running Windows 10 Pro since the last time I posted something here.
I want to be able to connect to my fileserver on my Ubuntu system. How can I do that?

Comment: use this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).